# Load JSON from REST API into ADX(Kusto) using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I'm facing following problem. I want do download a data from API in JSON format. It's schema is something like this:

```json
{'content':[{'id':12345,
'date':2023-07-25,
-more fields-
'car':{'Ford':{'color','year'}, 'Suzuki':{'color','year'}},
},
{
'id':45678,
'date':2023-07-24,
-more fields-
'car':{'Ford':{'color','year'}, 'Suzuki':{'color','year'}}
},
{
'id':98765,
'date':2023-07-23,
-more fields-
'car':{'Ford':{'color','year'}, 'Suzuki':{'color','year'}}
}],
'numOfPages':100,
'totalElements':1000
}
```

So returning JSON has three fields, `numOfPages` and `totalElements` describe the whole dataset, but in the `['content']` I can access several data entities with the same schema, which are the Readings.
I want to load the data into Kusto Data Explorer table, where the single entity like:

```json
{'id':12345,
'date':2023-07-25,
-more fields-
'car':{'Ford':{'color','year'}, 'Suzuki':{'color','year'}},
}
```

goes into single column and data with different id is in different rows.
I have used ADF web activities to collect data from API in this format, but I have trouble to do proper mapping as it's not clear how to access the root of the JSON `'Content'` field and divide the entities into different rows, so if my JSON has 5 entities in the `'Content'` it will generate 5 rows in the Kusto Table, which schema for now is a single column Readings, later I will work about adding more columns with ADF metadata.

Comment: Currently, by mapping `$['content']` to `Readings` column in the Copy Activity (which as source takes REST connector and as sink takes Kusto connector) I achieved that when I download JSON with 2 readings in the `['content']`, both of them are being loaded into single row in the Kusto Table. I would like to split these `Readings` into seperate rows.

Comment: `car':{'Ford':{'color','year'}, 'Suzuki':{'color','year'}}` are you sure that your JSON is valid in strcture? if not please provide the correct format of the JSON for better understanding

Comment: It's an example which should tell that my JSON doesn't have plain/flat structure with simple `key: normal value`, but is kind of nested, so some fields, like in the example `car`, are more developed. It's structure is not suitable for regular relational table. Nevertheless, JSON structure of `car` is not important, the most important thing is that the `content` field is a `[ ]` list with multiple `{ }` entities with `id` and other fields. I would like to somehow load these entities into separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your scenario with the sample data like below.

```
{
    "content":
    [
        {
            "id":12345,
            "dat":"2023-07-25",
            "car":
            {
                "Ford":
                {
                    "color":"yellow",
                    "year":"2012"
                }, 
                "Suzuki":
                {
                    "color":"red",
                    "year":"2013"
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "id":45678,
        "dat":"2023-07-24",
        "car":
            {
                "Ford":
                {
                    "color":"Blue",
                    "year":"2012"
                }, 
                "Suzuki":
                {
                    "color":"whilte",
                    "year":"2013"
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "id":98765,
        "dat":"2023-07-23",
        "car":
            {
                "Ford":
                {
                    "color":"Black",
                    "year":"2012"
                }, 
                "Suzuki":
                {
                    "color":"Violete",
                    "year":"2013"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
"numOfPages":100,
"totalElements":1000
}
```

Here, if you want to get the array `Content` as row values in a table, then the column values `numOfPages`,`totalElements` also will be repeated as the number of rows in the array.

Here, I have given the below mapping in the copy activity using advanced editor.

[image]

Give the data types of the target as per your requirement. But for the columns like `car` use the string type only. When I tried it using `dynamic` and disabled the **`Map complex values to string`** option above, I got the below error saying that object is not supported.

[image]

So, I opted for the string data type in the target for the object columns.

**Target table:**

[image]

Use `parse_json()` in ADX to use the JSON string as JSON object.

[image]